# After porting some php and web app related files from my friend's windows computer to my mac I'm getting some errors

Tags: session, heroku, facebook-apps, php

This is for a facebook app being run on heroku, but heroku is probably not the issue. The issue is either some kind of cache related thing, os porting, or I'm thinking it might be a carriage return issue.

In any case I'm getting a couple errors at the top and bottom respectively:

```
Warning: Unknown: 
Warning: session_start(): open(C:\ProgramData\Jcx.Software\VS.Php\2.10.6970.0\temp/sess_i4ood4poc11ebsgth000g1nm74, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /app/www/sdk/src/facebook.php on line 37

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /app/www/sdk/src/facebook.php:37) in /app/www/sdk/src/facebook.php on line 37 
open(C:\ProgramData\Jcx.Software\VS.Php\2.10.6970.0\temp/sess_i4ood4poc11ebsgth000g1nm74, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in Unknown on line 0 Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (C:\ProgramData\Jcx.Software\VS.Php\2.10.6970.0\temp) in Unknown on line 0
```

Essentially I have tried the whole "making sure session is at the top thing," but I don't have that session piece of code in any of the files. I have tried the whole making sure "?>" is on a new line as well to no effect.

**update**

I have discovered something called: 
zend_extension_ts="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jcx.Software\VS.Php\2010\php 5.2\ext\php_xdebug.dll"

within a file called php.ini which even after I tried to get rid of didn't seem to change anything. So, I'm thinking this has something to do with some previous files that I pushed and then removed with extensions like puo, intellisense.cache, projphp, etc.

I don't know if those are auto-generated or not, but in any case according to my errors:

- There is some session data in a file called temp. I have no file named temp.
- zend_extension_ts supposedly gets referenced somewhere, but it isn't visible in my code.
- I apparently need to resend session cache limiter again through session_start() which is not visible in my code.

Comment: Looks like `C:\ProgramData\Jcx.Software\VS.Php\2.10.6970.0\temp` is hardcoded somewhere. That path obviously does not exist on a Mac...

Comment: yes, I know that. But its not present in any of my php files and I have no files in my sdk directory

Comment: There are a few locations where this could be set: php.ini, .htaccess or another .php file - after editing your php.ini, make sure to restart the web server as well.

Comment: @Jack, I've checked and it was in php.ini so I deleted php.ini. As far as restarting the web server, its Heroku so I did Heroku restart and nothing changed.

Comment: Not familiar with Heroku, but if `C:\ProgramData\Jcx.Software\VS.Php\2.10.6970.0\temp` still shows up in your error messages, you didn't  remove it from ... somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

Is not the session , I'm sure. But there is directory path included in your code but that directory does not exist! Just refactor that part of the code first!

As a tip you should use realpath() and check if path exist before attempting to use it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: no need I deleted that file with that directory path, and the problem still exists. Its probably some cache related issue.

Comment: can you paste a copy of your code so we can all see what's going on?

Comment: well its essentially just the basic facebook getting started heroku tutorial code, and I'm thinking this issue is more Heroku than php actually.